# Passing ID from View to Controller (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

I'm trying to pass an Id from a view to a controller HttpPost action method.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        ...

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult List()
        {
            var currentUserId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var currentCars = db.Cars.Where(x => x.CreatedByUserId == currentUserId)
                .Select( x => new CarsListViewModel
                 {
                   CarId = x.Id,
                   CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                   CreatedByUserId = x.CreatedByUserId,
                   CreatedByUserName = x.CreatedByUserName,
                   Firstname = x.PrimaryData.Firstname,
                   Lastname = x.PrimaryData.Lastname
                  }).
                ToList();

            return View(currentCars);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult List(int carId)
        {
            var Car = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == carId);

                db.Cars.Remove(Car);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return View();
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CarListViewModel
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

        public string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (List.cshtml):

```
@model List<CVBuilder.ViewModels.CarListViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "List of current cars";
}

<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
    <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
        <thead>

            ...

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model[i].CreatedOn</td>
                <td>@Model[i].CreatedByUserName</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Firstname</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Lastname</td>
                <td>

                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="carId" value="@Model[i].CarId" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    @if (Model.Count == 0)
    {
    <div class="text-center"><p>No cars created.</p></div>
    }

</div>
```

Comment: what is the value of `Car` variable in the Post method? I suspect value of `carId` is 0

Comment: you should change the button declation in view with something like this. `<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName",Model[i].CarId)'">`. There is no need to pass value using hidden field.

Comment: carId is not 0 in the Post method. It gets the correct Id but I am getting the NullReferenceException in my View. Visual Studio points the for cycle and line value="@Model[i].CarId" gets null.

Comment: which line can you please tell?

Comment: View: <input type="hidden" name="carId" value="@Model[i].CarId" />

Comment: Try this `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CarId);` @warrior7

Comment: I tried with `<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("List", "Home",Model[i].CarId)'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>` but now carId in Post method is 0.

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CarId);` with this one carId in Post method is 0 also.

Comment: And what about other properties those you have in `td`, is it displaying their values? Can you also change the parameter name to `CarId`?

Comment: All properties in my View are displayed properly. If I change the parameter name to CarId there is no change in the value. It is 0.

Comment: Can you also try to display the `CarId` as well and see what value is it showing

Comment: View displays the correct CarId. By the way I changed the Post method `return RedirectToAction("List")` and everything is working now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
     public IActionResult List([FromForm]int carId){

     //  return View(); remove
     return RedirectToAction("List")
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error: 
_System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null._

Comment: after you post (delete action) your viewmodel make empty. instance od return view() put  return RedirectToAction("List")

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to pass a particular model id from view to controller in MVC

```html
<button href="@Url.Action("List", "ControllerName", new { carId = @Model[i].CarId},null)" button>
```